# How to get ID, class and name of child divs from Parent Div ID in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to get ID's of child div's have "ClonablePart class" in following HTML?

```
<div id="Finance_panel" class="panel>
 <div id="Finance_panel1" class="panel clonablePart"></div>
 <div id="Finance_panel2" class="panel clonablePart"></div>
 <div id="Finance_panel3" class="panel clonablePart"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tL9spngx/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` function to get the object of returned properties in it along with `.get()` to convert into array:

```
$('#Finance_panel .clonablePart').map(function(){
  return this.id;
}).get();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m81cq0kc/)**

Comment: `toArray()` is more intuitive than `get()` imo.

Comment: `toArray()` is more intuitive than `get()` imo.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should fix the HTML because it has a typo that could cause errors; add a double quote at the end of the class value of the first div.

To get the id's of the target elements, first select the target elements. Then, loop through the elements to do whatever it is you want to do with the id's, for example, console.log them, change them, add them to an array, concatenate them, etc.

So, using this HTML (typo fixed):

```
<div id="Finance_panel" class="panel">
    <div id="Finance_panel1" class="panel clonablePart"></div>
    <div id="Finance_panel2" class="panel clonablePart"></div>
    <div id="Finance_panel3" class="panel clonablePart"></div>
</div>
```

You can use this JS to get the desired id's:

```
$("#Finance_panel").find(".clonablePart").each(function () {
    var id = this.id;

    // Replace the console.log statement below with whatever operation you want to perform with the id
    console.log("The id of this div is " + id);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqzmfhvf/)

Answer (score 0):

User attr property of jquery to get any HTML tag attributes

```
var lengthPanel = $("#Finance_panel").find('.clonablePart');
var class = lengthPanel.attr('class');
var id = lengthPanel.attr('id');
var style = lengthPanel.attr('style');
```